# Can I apply for a new UK visit visa when I have still Valid UK visitor visa?

Tags: visas, valid

My exam was on 26th of March and which was cancelled due to this covid pandemic, but I applied for visa on that exam date, now that i have got the 6month visitor visa which is valid till 14th of september, 2021. Now the issue is that the earliest exam that I could book was 10th of october, 2021 and my visa will ve expired by that time.Now i am confused that can I apply for a new visitor visa while still having a valid uk visitor visa. please guide what to do in this situation

Comment: Do you intend to visit the UK at all using your existing visa? AFAIK there is nothing in the rules to prevent you from applying for a new visa before your current visa expires. You’ll have to explain about the rescheduled exam anyway, the situation will be clear to UKVI.

Comment: no i have no plans of travelling on my existing visa, thanks alot